# Code coverage with vue 2, typescript, mocha and karma

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, vuejs2, karma-runner

We are using Vue 2 in combination with Typescript and webpack 3. Vuex is used for state management. Our tests is run with Karma together with Mocha, Sinon, Expect and Avoriaz. Everything works great but I trying to get code coverage using Istanbul to work to get a better visual representation of what tests are missing.

**Small representation of the folder structure**

- src

  - components

    - shared
    - button

      - button.vue
      - button.ts
  - index.ts
  - ...
- tests

  - unit

    - components

      - shared
      - button

        - button.spec.test.ts
  - karma.conf.js
  - karma.coverage.js
  - index.ts
  - ...

**button.vue**

```html
<template>
    <button onClick="handleClick" visible="visible"></button>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./button.ts"></script>
```

**button.ts**

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class Button extends Vue {

    @Prop({ default: false })
    public visible: boolean;

    private onClick() {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

I currently have not even created a button.spec.ts at all which is something I am trying to get the team to tackle using this informatoin and this is the result from the code coverage:

[image: Code coverage]

The coverage in general in the project:

```
✔ 332 tests completed
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 43.88% ( 1847/4209 )
Branches     : 36.83% ( 952/2585 )
Functions    : 32.97% ( 456/1383 )
Lines        : 45.28% ( 1732/3825 )
================================================================================
```

But in general, the results are not actually showing the code coverage at all. Every file is like this:

[image: Code lines]

My questions

- How do I get a better result for this? Am I missing something basic about code coverage?
- How do I code cover functions that are only run in .vue-files?

Other files that might be related:

**karma.coverage.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
    files: [
      'index.ts'
    ],
    reporters: reporters,
    preprocessors: {
      'index.ts': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'reports/'
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [{
        type: 'json',
        dir: '../../coverage/',
        subdir: '.'
      },
      {
        type: 'text-summary'
      },
    ]
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS_custom'],
    customLaunchers: {
        'PhantomJS_custom': {
            base: 'PhantomJS',
            options: {
                windowName: 'my-window',
                settings: {
                    webSecurityEnabled: false
                },
            },
            flags: ['--remote-debugger-port=9003', '--remote-debugger-autorun=yes'],
            debug: false
        }
    },
    phantomjsLauncher: {
        // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
        exitOnResourceError: true
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
    },
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

**unit/index.ts**

```js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

function requireAll(r: any): any {
    r.keys().forEach(r);
}

requireAll((require as any).context('./', true, /spec.ts$/));
requireAll((require as any).context('../../src/', true, /^(?!.*(main)).*ts$/));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, that you should use use [vue-unit](https://github.com/wrseward/vue-unit).

For example your test case could look like:

```
import { beforeEachHooks, afterEachHooks, mount, waitForUpdate, simulate } from 'vue-unit'
import Button from '@/components/Button'

describe('Button', () => {
  beforeEach(beforeEachHooks)

 it('should render with hidden class if visible is set to false', () => {
     const vm = mount(Button, {
         visible: false //you can ass properties
     })

     expect(vm.$el).to.have.class('hidden') //example assertions, needs chai-dom extension
  })

  afterEach(afterEachHooks)
})
```

You can also check result of single methods:

```
 const vm = mount(Button)

 expect(vm.$el.somemethod('val')).to.be('result')
 //method declared in methods block
```

You should also consider adding extensions to chai, like [chai-dom](https://github.com/nathanboktae/chai-dom) or [sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai), which would allow you to create more flexible assertions:

```
it('should invoke onClick handler when button is clicked', () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy()

    const vm = mount(Button, {
      onClick: spy
    })

    simulate(vm.$el, 'click')

    expect(spy).to.be.called
  })
```

You can configure it in `karma.conf.js`:

```
//karma.conf.js
...
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai-dom', 'sinon-chai', 'phantomjs-shim'],
...
```

IMHO Your code coverage configuration looks fine, so if you add tests for your components it should boost your stats.